# click a html div element in flutter

Tags: html, flutter, dart, web-scraping

I have this code:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;

 final String pagina =
'https://www.bportugal.pt/simplesaml/module.php/core/authenticate.php?return_url=//www.bportugal.pt';

Future getWebsiteData() async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
      pagina,
    );
    final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Required for CORS support to work
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":
          'true', // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Accept",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET"
    });
    dom.Document html = dom.Document.html(response.body);
    (html.querySelector(
                '#ctl00_ctl00_NestedMasterPage_divTexto_CompaniesATRow > div.col-xs-12.col-md-1.bdp-image-margin.bdp-adjust-ml.img-responsive > div')
            a**s Element).click();**
    //.dispatchEvent( MouseEvent('Click'));
    //(html.querySelector('password-nif') as InputElement).click();
    //(document.querySelector('sbmtLogin') as ButtonElement).click();
    print('ola');
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRrYA.png)

I have to click on the 'HTML div' to navigate to another page, however as the DIV is just an Element, it doesn't have that 'Click' functionality.
Does anyone know of a solution for this?

I tried with the following Javascript, but Flutter doesn't recognize the command 'runJavascript' (html.runJavascript("document.getElementById('btnId').click()"));